# Returning a CollapsiblePanelExtender over/through ajax/javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, collapsiblepanelextender

I would like to be able to return a programmatically generated collapsible panel extender through javascript along with it's panel and so on. I've got the panel and associated tables going through just fine however when I try and attach the cpe it breaks. and returns an error:

The cpe panel and such are being generaged by a WebService and I'm trying to get JS to write what the webservice returns to a particular field dynamically

`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'Sub_Menu_Helper' failed with the following error: System.InvalidOperationException-- Page cannot be null. Please ensure that this operation is being performed in the context of an ASP.NET request.`

```
                {
                    Label somelabel = new Label();
                    somelabel.ID = somenumber.ToString();
                    somelabel.Text = somenumber.ToString();
                    subpnlContent.Controls.Add(somelabel);
                    ++somenumber;
                }

                CollapsiblePanelExtender cpeMenuLast = new CollapsiblePanelExtenderEx();
                cpeMenuLast.ID = "subcpe" + strMenuId + strParentHierarchyIds;
                cpeMenuLast.TargetControlID = "subpnlContent" + strParentMenuId + "_" + strMenuId;
                cpeMenuLast.ExpandControlID = "cellContent" + strParentMenuId + "_" + strMenuId;
                cpeMenuLast.CollapseControlID = "cellContent" + strParentMenuId + "_" + strMenuId;
                cpeMenuLast.Collapsed = bCollapsed;
                cpeMenuLast.TextLabelID = strMenuName;
                cpeMenuLast.ExpandedText = m_strButtonLabelHide;
                cpeMenuLast.CollapsedText = m_strButtonLabelShow;
                cpeMenuLast.ImageControlID = "imglnk" + strMenuId;
                cpeMenuLast.CollapsedImage = "~/App_Themes/default/nbExpand.gif";
                cpeMenuLast.ExpandedImage = "~/App_Themes/default/nbCollapse.gif";
                cpeMenuLast.SuppressPostBack = true;
                cpeMenuLast.ScrollContents = false;

                //Add Everything
                cellSubMenu.Controls.Add(subpnlContent);
                cellSubMenu.Controls.Add(cpeMenuLast);
                row.Cells.Add(cellSubMenu);
                tbl.Rows.Add(row);

                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
                {
                    using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        tbl.RenderControl(tw);
                    }
                }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a `Page` object with a `ScriptManager` to render the `CollapsiblePanelExtender`, which makes sense since you need some script for it to work properly.

So maybe you can try the following way to render your table:

```
var page = new Page();
page.Controls.Add(new ScriptManager());
page.Controls.Add(tbl);
var writer = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
return writer.ToString();
```

Oliver